# How to mark Laravel Notifications that just came in

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page that displays all of the user's notifications. I want to highlight notifications that has not yet been read by the user.

However, when I use

```
$notifications = tap(auth()->user()->notifications)->markAsRead();
```

It automatically marks all the notifications as read and I am unable to tell the blade file which notifications are those that have already been read and which notifications are those that the user has not yet seen since he/she last visited the notifications page. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should just use `unreadNotifications` instead of `notifications`, therefore you'll mark them as read but you'll know that everyone of them was unread.

Comment: But how do I tell which notifications are just read if all are marked as read?

Comment: When you use `unreadNotifications`, you retrieve only notifications which weren't read until now, so you don't need to mind about that.